# SSAS can not allocate more memory even when 'TotalMemoryLimit' is set to a high level

Tags: memory, ssas

we have a server with 144GB memory, and running Sql Server and Analysis Services.

from analysis server setting panel, the 'TotalMemoryLimit' is set to 70, and 'LowMemoryLimit' is set to 55.

but the memory of SSAS is always around 18GB, and can not allocate more, even when there're lots of memory available.

processing job can not be done when there's not enough memory for SSAS.
it's in production environment, so i can't restart the server easily.

by the way, we dynamic adjust the totalmemorylimit and lowmemorylimit to make analysis services release memory.

it went well for several month, but the problem happened this morning.
and no matter how i set the 'totalmemorylimit' and lowmemorylimit, the memory of analysis is always around 18Gb

Comment: Is it Enterprise Edition? What else other than SSAS is installed?

Comment: yes, it's enterprise edition. and sql server was installed side by side. no other big stuffs

Answer (score 1):

It could be SQL server grabbing and reserving a working set that's too big.

In SQL Server, go to Server Properties / Memory/ Check Dynamic memory configuration and set the maximum server memory to something sensible to get it to share nicely with SSAS.

Better yet, buy a seperate server instance for SSAS.

Comment: i dont think so. we already limit the max memory usage of sql server, and by the time this problem happens, the total memory still have many left. anyway, i restart ssas in midnight and it 's ok now.